# Какой файл будет использоваться, применяя <?php echo get_category_link($id); ?>

Tags: wordpress

Какой файл будет использоваться, применяя 
Пробовал разные файлы создавать, что бы создать внешний вид страницы конкретной категории, но не могу понять какой файл нужен.

Вот код:

```
<div class="sort">
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link(even); ?>" class="sort__item">Все</a>
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link(19); ?>" class="sort__item">Landing</a>
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link(20); ?>" class="sort__item">Корпоративный</a>
        <a class="sort__item">Каталог</a>
        <a class="sort__item">Магазин</a>
        <a class="sort__item">Уникальный</a>
        <a class="sort__item">Тендерные работы</a>
        <a class="sort__item">Old works</a>
      </div>
```

Вот мой кастомный тип записей, для которого используется запрос.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это должна быть выборка категорий

Comment: Лол, у меня та же проблема, кто знает как решить?